# How do I get SVN out of a a "Cleanup/Add" loop?

Tags: svn

Running SVN from the command line on a RedHat box and when trying to remove some folders that were included accidently I ran into the following issue:

```
[USER@dev-box BNRCT]$ svn unlock trunk/
svn: Working copy '/home/USER/BNRCT' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)

[USER@dev-box BNRCT]$ svn cleanup trunk/
svn: In directory 'trunk/FOLDER/Tools/delivery'
svn: Error processing command 'modify-entry' in 
'trunk/FOLDER/Tools/delivery'
svn: Error modifying entry for 'st'
svn: 'st' is not under version control

[USER@dev-box BNRCT]$ svn add trunk/FOLDER/Tools/delivery/st
svn: Working copy 'trunk/FOLDER/Tools/delivery' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

`st` was the folder i was trying to remove, I am trying to avoid a reversion of the entire folder but I don't know how to get out of this loop.

Comment: Did you try listing and breaking lock? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.locking.html#svn.advanced.locking.break-steal

Comment: @Peska Yup, same results as the first shown command